# Creating a neural network with drag and drop in browser

Tags: javascript, neural-network, drag-drop

I'm working on an open-source project which enables the user to define the architecture of a neural network (similar to draw.io), provide the data, and train it in their browser. To define the architecture, I was hoping to create a platform in which the user can add the layers by dragging and dropping them from a list and then connect the layers to define the connections in the computation graph.

I was wondering if there is any javascript library that can handle the task by itself. If not, what are some useful libraries to build such a platform with, from scratch? I would also need another library to show a live plot for the training process (the loss function values, etc.). Btw, I'm using Vue.js for the application itself, and all the steps (designing the architecture, loading the data, and visualizing the training process) are all done in a single page.